# SQL delete unique row in table

Tags: t-sql, delete-row

I've got the following table:

```
PatientID | DiagID
```

...where `PatientID` is a unique identifier and `DiagID` is a diagnosis ID, which is not unique. How do I delete the patient from table who's got unique `DiagID` (the only in the table, who's got this specific `DiagID`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you want to delete any patients that only have a single instance of a diagnosis ID. In which case the SQL would be something like:

```
DELETE Patient
WHERE DiagID in
(SELECT DiagID FROM Patient GROUP BY DiagID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A delete where clause doesn't have to use the primary key, example:

```
Delete From Table
Where DiagID = 5
```

If you mean you want to delete all uniques, then something like:

```
Delete From Table
Where DiagID In (Select DiagID
                 From Table
                 Group By DiagID
                 HAVING count(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You say there's only one patient with this specific diagnosis id?

```
delete
from YourTable
where DiagID = @diagId
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know it is the only one then there is nothing wrong with this

```
DELETE FROM Patient 
WHERE DiagID = @inDiagID
```

If you want to be safe, something like this might be wise:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT DiagID FROM Patient WHERE DiagID = @inDiagID GROUP BY DiagID HAVING COUNT(DiagID) = 1)
BEGIN
      DELETE FROM Patient 
      WHERE DiagID = @inDiagID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to delete patients that only have one DiagID?

```
DELETE FROM table
    WHERE PatientID IN 
    ( SELECT DiagID FROM table
    GROUP BY DiagID 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Comment: The subquery should throw an error: no aggregate on DiagID. Fix that, and then given PatientID is always unique, then COUNT(*) is always 1. TRUNCATE TABLE would be quicker. -1

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE
    D
FROM
    DiagTable D
    JOIN
    (SELECT DiagID FROM DiagTable D2 GROUP BY DiagID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) foo ON D.DiagID = foo.DiagID
```

The subquery find unique (ie used once) DiagIDs. This is used to JOIN bak to delete rows for these unique DiagIDs

Answer (score 0):

you can use row_number and over partition by and sort by to determine which records are non unique diagnosis id then filter on those records with a where clause.  Using this subquery you can delete those rows.  I like to visually confirm the rows that are being deleted.